# Calculating expectation of functions across normal distribution

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I want to compute the expectation of certain functions across a normal distribution.

An example:

```py
mu = 100
k = 100
sigma = 10
val, err = quad(lambda x: norm.pdf((x - mu) / sigma) * x if x > k else 0, -math.inf, math.inf)
print(val)
```

This prints 4.878683842492743e-288 which is clearly not the correct answer.

I assume this is happening because SciPy is unable to integrate the Gaussian. How can I solve this? Ideally, I'd want a method that'd allows one to integrate all sorts of functions across Gaussian and is not specific to the example I have put in.

Thanks!

Comment: You are integrating wrt the N(0,1) density here so shouldn't the range be from 0 to +inf instead of k to +inf?

Comment: Suggest you double check the docs here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a problem with the quadrature (sometimes it doesn't really adapt), and doesn't like the if statement.

So I would suggest something like this (integrate from k to infinity):

```
def f(x):
    return 1/sigma*norm.pdf((x - mu) / sigma)*x

val, err = quad(f,  k, math.inf)
```

Notice, as implied by Jimmy, the correct form of the Gaussian needs 1/sigma.

Another way to do this integral would be to force quad to be careful at some points. My favorite way is to do something like

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad 

#this is the Gaussian. Note that *0.5*(np.sign(x-k)+1) is 0 for x<k and 1 otherwise.
def f(x):
    return 1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma)*np.exp(- 0.5*( (x-mu)/sigma )**2 ) *x*0.5*(np.sign(x-k)+1)
    
#use this to integrate from in (-1,1)
def G(u):
    x=u/(1-u**2)
    return f(x)*(1+u**2)/(1-u**2)**2

quad(G,-1,1,points=np.linspace(-0.999,0.999,25))
```

I would suggest to read [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html#general-integration-quad) in order to get how you can optimize such integrals.